# How to add toolbar item in TabbedPage in Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin, tabbedpage

Can you tell me how can I add toolbar item in a tabbed page in xamarin from.
thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
<TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem1" Order="Primary" Icon="Microsoft.png" Text="Item 1" Priority="0" />
    <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem2" Order="Primary" Icon="Xamarin.png" Text="Item 2" Priority="1" />
</TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Re: [Xamarin Forms Toolbar](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-toolbar/)

Comment: This is not the correct answer. it is asked for Tabbed page. you should use   <TabbedPage.ToolbarItems> instead.