# Showing ToolbarItem in Xamarin Forms with AppShell

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage, xamarin.forms.shell

In my Xamarin Forms 5 app, I'm trying to add a `ToolbarItem` to a `ContentPage` which is a "child" of a `TabbedPage` but the `ToolbarItem` is not showing.

The key point here is that the app uses `AppShell` and the tabs are defined in `AppShell.xaml` which looks like this:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Home">
   <FlyoutItem.Icon>
      <FontImageSource
         FontFamily="MISHRP"
         Glyph="{StaticResource HomeIcon}"
         Color="White" />
   </FlyoutItem.Icon>
   <ShellContent Route="HomePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

And the home page has three tabs that point to `ContentPage`'s:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            ... // Removed for brevity>
    <local:CommercialFeed Title="Feed" />
    <local:PersonalCard Title="Card" />
    <local:Vendors Title="Vendors" />
</TabbedPage>
```

I'm now adding a `ToolbarItem` in the "Vendors" page but it doesn't show. I read that I need to wrap main page in a `NavigationPage`.

I have two issues here:

1. Because I'm using AppShell, my code behind looks like this: `MainPage = new AppShell();`. So not sure how to handle this part. I tried `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new AppShell());` but this created another issue -- see below -- and it also crashed the app.
2. I have a login page which is also defined in the `AppShell`. When I tried the above code, I got a nav bar on the login page as well and that's a problem. There shouldn't be a nav bar in the login page.

How do I handle this so that I can have `ToolbarItems` in my Vendors page? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I believe it is a bad idea to mix `Shell` and the old `TabbedPage` (use either one of them), in my opinion it is better to change your ui structure from `TabbedPage` to a combination of `Tabbar` and `Tab` that both are within `Shell` [Xamarin.Forms Shell tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs).

```
    <TabBar>

        <Tab Title="Feed">
            <ShellContent Title="Feed" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:CommercialFeed}"/>
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Cards">
            <ShellContent Title="Cards" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate PersonalCard}"/>
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Vendors">
            <ShellContent Title="Vendors" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Vendors}"/>
        </Tab>

    </TabBar>
```

Now define `ToolbarItems` on each page:

```
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="..." .../>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

If you want to keep using `TabbedPage` anyway, check [How to add toolbar item in TabbedPage in Xamarin Form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46946664/)

Comment: I'm learning as I go. I agree that defining tabs in `AppShell` seems like a cleaner approach. Thank you!